# value only needs to show up 1 time in its field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need "Hrs Week" value to only show up 1 time in its field, as its the total hours spent working per week. now the value gets repeated for every line, its over 3000 lines so much repeated lines with the same info. as you can see i have been trying with a left join, to see if it would work

```
SELECT  
(SELECT  TOP 1
       (SELECT
       MAX(process_progress_time_used)
       FROM
       PROCESS_PROGRESS PRP
       WHERE
       process_id = 18776)
       -
       (SELECT  
       process_progress_time_used
       FROM
       PROCESS_PROGRESS PRP
       WHERE
       process_id = 18776  
       AND DATEDIFF (WEEK, process_progress_date ,GETDATE()) = 1)
FROM PROCESS_PROGRESS PRP
WHERE 
   PRO.process_id = PRP.process_id) AS 'Hrs Week',

 PRO#A.process_no AS 'Activity', 
 PRO.process_no AS 'Job', 
 PRO.process_name, 
 department_no AS 'DepartmentNo', 
 [dbo].[activities].current_progress, 
 (SELECT
  process_progress_time_used 
FROM
  [dbo].[PROCESS_PROGRESS] 
WHERE
  process_id = PRO.process_id  
  AND resource_def_seq = PRO.resource_def_seq
  AND process_progress_date = ( SELECT max(process_progress_date) FROM [dbo].[PROCESS_PROGRESS] PRG# WHERE PRG#.process_id = PRO.process_id AND PRG#.resource_def_seq = PRO.resource_def_seq)) Used_Hours
FROM
    [dbo].[PROCESS] PRO
    JOIN PROCESS_TYPE PTY ON PTY.process_type_id = PRO.process_type_id
    AND PTY.process_type_no IN ('JOB','JOBB')
 JOIN [dbo].[JOB] ON PRO.process_id = JOB.process_id
 --LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PROCESS_PROGRESS] ON PRP.process_progress_time_used
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PROCESS] PRO#A ON PRO.process_owner_id = PRO#A.process_id
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[activities] ON PRO#A.process_activities_seq = [dbo].[activities].seq AND PRO#A.process_activities_net_id = [dbo].[activities].net_id 
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DEPARTMENT] DEP ON PRO.department_id = DEP.department_id
 JOIN [dbo].[networks] NET ON NET.net_id = PRO#A.process_activities_net_id
 ORDER BY 4,1
```

Comment: OH! my bad noticed it now, edited the tags.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want an optimization of this? Please add sample data and an expected result would also very helpful ;)

Comment: You really should break the habit of ordering by ordinal position. If you ever change your query you will get incorrect results unless you also remember to change the order by. Just use column names or aliases and avoid the headache.

Comment: Using subqueries as columns is an indication that your query is not well formed. You have subqueries nested multiple levels deep in your columns. This needs to completely rethought from the beginning. What would really help here is a [mcve].